# Pandas Divide dataframe by index values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I am trying to divide all columns in the dataframe by the index.(1221 rows, 1000 columns)

```
           5000058004097  5000058022936  5000058036940  5000058036827  \

91.0        3.667246e+10   3.731947e+12   2.792220e+14   2.691262e+13   
94.0        9.869027e+10   1.004314e+13   7.514220e+14   7.242529e+13   
96.0        2.536914e+11   2.581673e+13   1.931592e+15   1.861752e+14
...
```

Here is the code I have tried...

```
A = SHIGH.divide(SHIGH.index, axis =1)
```

and I get this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1221,1000) (1221,)
```

I have also tried

```
A = SHIGH.divide(SHIGH.index.values.tolist(), axis =1)
```

and also  reindexing and using the column to divide and get the same error.

If someone could please point out my mistake it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `Index` object to a `Series`:

```
df.div(df.index.to_series(), axis=0)
```

Example:

```
In [118]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3))
df

Out[118]:
          0         1         2
0  0.828540 -0.574005 -0.535122
1 -0.126242  2.152599 -1.356933
2  0.289270 -0.663178 -0.374691
3 -0.016866 -0.760110 -1.696402
4  0.130580 -1.043561  0.789491

In [124]:
df.div(df.index.to_series(), axis=0)

Out[124]:
          0         1         2
0       inf      -inf      -inf
1 -0.126242  2.152599 -1.356933
2  0.144635 -0.331589 -0.187345
3 -0.005622 -0.253370 -0.565467
4  0.032645 -0.260890  0.197373
```

Answer (score 2):

You need convert index [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and then divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
print (SHIGH.divide(SHIGH.index.to_series(), axis = 0))
      5000058004097  5000058022936  5000058036940  5000058036827
91.0   4.029941e+08   4.101041e+10   3.068374e+12   2.957431e+11
94.0   1.049896e+09   1.068419e+11   7.993851e+12   7.704818e+11
96.0   2.642619e+09   2.689243e+11   2.012075e+13   1.939325e+12
```

In both solutions `timings` are same:

```
SHIGH = pd.DataFrame({'5000058022936': {96.0: 25816730000000.0, 91.0: 3731947000000.0, 94.0: 10043140000000.0}, 
                 '5000058036940': {96.0: 1931592000000000.0, 91.0: 279222000000000.0, 94.0: 751422000000000.0}, 
                 '5000058036827': {96.0: 186175200000000.0, 91.0: 26912620000000.0, 94.0: 72425290000000.0}, 
                 '5000058004097': {96.0: 253691400000.0, 91.0: 36672460000.0, 94.0: 98690270000.0}})


print (SHIGH)
      5000058004097  5000058022936  5000058036827  5000058036940
91.0   3.667246e+10   3.731947e+12   2.691262e+13   2.792220e+14
94.0   9.869027e+10   1.004314e+13   7.242529e+13   7.514220e+14
96.0   2.536914e+11   2.581673e+13   1.861752e+14   1.931592e+15

#[1200 rows x 1000 columns] in sample DataFrame
SHIGH = pd.concat([SHIGH]*400).reset_index(drop=True)
SHIGH = pd.concat([SHIGH]*250, axis=1)

In [212]: %timeit (SHIGH.divide(SHIGH.index.values, axis = 0))
100 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ms per loop

In [213]: %timeit (SHIGH.divide(SHIGH.index.to_series(), axis = 0))
100 loops, best of 3: 14.9 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is

```
df.div(df.index.values, axis=0)
```

Example:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5), 'b': range(1, 6), 'c': range(2, 7)}).set_index('a')

In [8]: df.divide(df.index.values, axis=0)
Out[8]: 
          b         c
a                    
0       inf       inf
1  2.000000  3.000000
2  1.500000  2.000000
3  1.333333  1.666667
4  1.250000  1.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHIGH / SHIGH.index
```

df.index gives you an array-like structure which stores the indices.